# Is it safe to partition a disk NTFS and HFS+?

Tags: partitioning

Is it safe to partition an external hard disk NTFS and HFS+?

If I have a Windows and a Mac system but want to write data to an external hard disk, what is the best partition to use?

Answer (score 1):

It's safe, but probably doesn't make much sense if you want them to be accessible for both Windows and macOS. Use UDF or exFAT.